# Cross platform mobile development solution with fastest initial start-up

Tags: c#, android, performance, xamarin, startup

I am currently using Xamarin to code for both Android and iOS. I love C# and the fact that I am backed by Microsoft makes me feel very secure. However, a very simple app I built takes around 2 seconds to initially start. With this I mean the time it takes for any UI to appear, thus it's not my code's fault. I am planning on building a very big app and a start-up time of 2 seconds, especially growing up, is really scaring me. Is there something I can do about this? If not, is there a faster cross-platform mobile development solution that I can use for free?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I am testing this on an Android phone.

Comment: This is a valid question. Not sure why it was downvoted. Here have my upvote! A year later what happened with the app?

Comment: Unfortunately the project got cancelled, so no news there. However, the general Xamarin start-up time is getting exponentially smaller, due to a more optimized runtime, Android core, and of course more powerful phone hardware :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two seconds is fast enough and the usual time load for Android and iOS with an unexecuted app.

Usually the applications what do is to have an splash screen which shows an image and then it loads the app.

Here is described for android:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/

And here for iOS:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Comment: My app is as simple as saying that it's an empty app. The layout of an Android-equivalent version loads **instantly**. I will soon be creating a school app and a delay of 2+ seconds every time you want to see your schedule while running late for classes is enough for people to hate it. Is native Android (Java) coding the only way?

Comment: You must differentiate between *cold start* and *warm start*, cold start is always slower as the program must be loaded on memory, but it usually happens just once unless the app is killed, warm start will be a lot faster. Also, check the difference between debug and release builds and with the debugger attached or not. Using Xamarin adds an overhead, but that overhead will not grow when your app grows, so the difference would be compared to a native app of just 2 seconds. As cross development Xamarin is the fastest out there, if you don't want these startup times, write fully native apps.

Comment: I believe I am comparing cold starts in both cases - when the app is closed from "Recents". I have a Nexus 5X with arm64 processor. I am comparing a release build with Xamarin vs. a release build with Android Studio, both optimized for arm64. I downloaded two of Xamarin's own sample apps and they take up to 5 seconds to load every single time, which is unacceptable in my case. If I go for a HTML5/JS-based alternative, is the speed going to be the same?

Comment: Hmmm, depends on how you will do it, *the app* may load faster, but the interface will load a lot slower as HTML5 must load the page from the local resources, interpret it and render it, also, the program itself will be a lot slower unless its the most simplest possible program.

Comment: I would avoid as much as possible to use HTML5, if you *really* need the app to load that faster then the only way is native apps, but first consider it again, the usual is that your app be already open, so when the user gets back to the app the load is instantaneous.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your comments. Is there a way to keep the app 'warm starting' even when it's removed from recents?

Comment: Nope, when you remove the app from recents you're really killing it, that forces always a cold start.

Comment: Do you know if the same problem exists for the iOS version?

Comment: iOS usually is faster, but Xamarin will always have a bit of overhead as it must initialize the mono framework.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! You definitely made me cautious of these little details.